# Is my answer correct for indefinite integral $\int \frac{xe^x}{\sqrt{1+e^x}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Question: $$\int \frac{xe^x}{\sqrt{1+e^x}} dx$$

If my answer given below is correct, is there an easier way of computing this integral? I feel like this took too long to solve.

[image]

---

Comment: Fixed the addition sign in my answer

Comment: I noticed that the w in w/ (w^2-1) is supposed to be w^2. But this still gives a different answer than the correct answer

Comment: I am fixing my answer right now and will update the post when I am done

Comment: question is updated now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t=e^x$ to rewrite the integral,

$$I=\int \frac{xe^x}{\sqrt{1+e^x}}dx=\int \frac{\ln t}{\sqrt{1+t}}dt$$
Integrate by parts,

$$I = 2\sqrt{1+t}\ln t - 2\int \frac{\sqrt{1+t}}{t}dt\tag 1$$

Then, with $u=\sqrt{1+t}>1$,

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+t}}{t}dt=\int \frac{2u^2}{u^2-1}du=2u +\int \frac2{u^2-1}du
=2u+\ln\frac{u-1}{u+1}$$

Plug into (1) to obtain

$$I = 2\sqrt{1+t}\ln t - 4u + 2\ln\frac{u-1}{u+1} + C$$
$$ = 2x\sqrt{1+e^x}- 4\sqrt{1+e^x} + 2\ln\frac{\sqrt{1+e^x} +1}{\sqrt{1+e^x} -1} + C$$

Comment: Do the absolute value brackets around the expression inside the natural log in your final answer  matter?

Comment: @Jtheconstant - It does not matter in the end, since the variables of the log can not be negative.

Comment: Oh I see. But say if the expression inside the natural log of your final answer was x or 1-e^x, where it can take negative values. Would this require the absolute value brackets in the final answer then?

Comment: @Jtheconstant - In that case, yes.